# Wine, Wineskin, or Winebottler for IOS?

Tags: ios, wine

I've survived for two months or more without my MacBook Pro but I **really** miss a Windows app called [Azuon](http://www.Azuon.com).  With that, I'd set up a search in ten seconds, start it, and come back a half-hour later to find what would have taken me days with Kayak, SkyScanner, Adioso, Momondo, Matrix, Rome2Rio, etc.

I did a web search but the only hit was an Italian video that had "IOS" in the title but had a MacOS screen for the whole first minute.  I can read Italian, but I can't follow it as audio without the help of lip reading.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to run Windows apps on IOS.  (Actually run them on IOS, not on a networked Windows host via RDP, Citrix, VNC, etc.)

I can't even try to port Wine myself, since I don't have anything to run XCode on.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Wine or similar for iOS. Besides probably being in conflict with Apple's Guidelines iPhones/iPads are not running on Intel chips so the Windows binaries wouldn't be usable anyway.

Having said that, there are apps like Hipmunk, Kayak etc. available for iOS which provide flight search functionality.

Comment: Yes, I have used Hipmunk also.  All the ones I mentioned and many more are useful, but no comparison to Azuon.  In a half-hour (or less) unattended, Azuon can give me a thousand options, sorted by price.  Then I investigate the best ten or so on other services.  To get those ten with anything else I've tried would take many hours of typing and clicking.

Comment: I doubt there's any license conflict, but the CPU issue is definitely a problem.  Guess I need to fix my laptop.

Comment: Apple is rather restrictive with apps which allow the execution of arbitrary user-provided code, which would exactly what a Windows emulator would be doing.

Answer (score 3):

You need an Intel/AMD chip to run Wine so running on an Apple chip (A7, A8 A9...) is simply not going to happen.

From the [Wine FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#What_are_the_system_requirements_for_Wine.3F):

> 2.9.2 Can I use Wine on an older Mac without an Intel chip?
>
> No, not even in Linux. Older Macs used PowerPC processors are
>   incompatible with code compiled for x86 (Intel and AMD) processors,
>   unless the code is run under CPU emulation. Wine Is Not a (CPU)
>   Emulator, nor does it include one. The Darwine project was an effort
>   to do just that, but it has not been maintained in many years.

While the statement is about PowerPC CPUs, the key here is **Wine is not a CPU emulator.** Meaning if the CPU isn't supported, it's simply not going to work.  A recompile won't make the missing APIs suddenly available.

While there is some *limited* [support for running on ARM chips](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM#Running_Windows.2Fx86_Applications), it's pretty much unsupported when it comes to x86 applications:

> This configuration is not supported, but you'll be able to run some
>   Applications. Don't ask for support on winehq.org,

Your best bet is to get [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/), [Citrix iOS Receiver](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/ios/) (Requires XenDesktop), [Microsoft RDP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id714464092?mt%3D8) or some other RDP client for iOS and run your app that way.

Comment: I understand the bit about the CPU, but none of your alternatives will work either.  They not only require an Intel CPU, but require it to be in another machine that I can connect to remotely.  That's why I explicitly said "not on a networked Windows host."

Comment: You don't need a *physical* node; you can virtualize one using [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) (free) or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) (Licensed) then RDP to that machine.  If you need something to get around network limitations, consider looking at a VM in the cloud with [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/)  You can do a "pay-as-you-go" plan and only pay for the compute you actually use.  Bottom line:  nothing will emulate an intel CPU on an iPhone/iPad CPU to run x86 apps on iOS

Comment: VirtualBox, Parallels, and Fusion also don't run on an iPad.

Comment: Not what I mean...You can put those on an *existing* machine connected to the network and run your app there or you can create a VM in the cloud with Azure.

Comment: If I had another machine, I'd just run Azuon the way I did before it died.

Comment: A "VM in the cloud" is by definition networked.  Thus NOT compatible with my network limitations!  Anyway, I rebuilt the Macbook Pro and got Azuon working again.

Answer (score -3):

I see no one else has suggested WIneskin!  FInd out more at http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php., or Codeweavers Crossover check out at www.paulthetall.com, or perhaps Wine BOttler, just google it.

Comment: I DID mention Wineskin, but since it doesn't work on IOS, why should anyone else mention it?  Please read questions before "answering" them.